# Prevent Excel from automatically converting numbers and dates based on clipboard contents

Tags: c#, .net, excel, text, clipboard

I have a data reporting application (.NET Desktop application) that I work on where users often copy data from my application and paste it into other applications especially Excel. However, sometimes the formatting of the data gets incorrectly interpretted by Excel as a date or a number when it should be treated as text. I have buttons that place data into the user's clipboard for this purpose, and am wondering if there is a way I could hold my users' hands a little bit and automatically mark the cells so that Excel knows that the data is NOT numerical data.

I know how to paste special, or paste as text, or format the cells in Excel prior to pasting, I want to make it so that my users don't have to do that.

I have tried adding a space after the tab character, and adding the ' character to the front of the string and neither of them seem to prevent Excel interpretting the values as numbers when pasting the data into excel.

Examples of things that don't work as desired:
Clipboard Contents 1:

> account/tproduct/n1234567890000/t11-2021/n

Excel's rendering 1:

| account | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1.23457E+11 | Nov-21 |

Clipboard Contents 2:

> account/tproduct/n 1234567890000/t 11-2021/n

Excel's rendering 2:

| account | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1.23457E+11 | Nov-21 |

Clipboard Contents 3:

> account/tproduct/n'1234567890000/t'11-2021/n

Excel's rendering 3:

| account | product |
| --- | --- |
| '1234567890000 | '11-2011 |

Desired Output:

| account | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890000 | 11-2011 |

Comment: The current method is just raw text with delimitting characters such as /t for each cell, and /n for new rows.

Comment: Show examples of data that gets incorrectly interpreted. One method is to preceed with a single '. But is the source program re-interpreting the ' ?

Comment: Added Examples of what I've tried and the undesired results. the ' character does indeed prevent Excel from interpretting it as a number, but when pasted from the clipboard the ' character is actually rendered in the cell, which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: If you add a zero width non-joiner space (e.g., `\u200B`) before the *string*, it should be interpreted as a string literal, but of course the non-space remains (even though invisible). If it's just for presentation, it could be tolerable

Comment: @Jimi - I did not think of that. Probably not an ideal solution, but I may go this route if there's not a better way to do it. Or probably just not try to be so helpful for the user and make them deal with Excel being Excel.